# One or more field types are not installed properly - Sharepoint 2010 Error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I got an STP template file to create and add some columns in a list.

I uploaded that list template(STP file) and created a new list in my local host site

but while I tried to click and see the list fields it showing following error. why this

error is coming ? how to solve this... can somebody help me??

Error:

One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.

Correlation ID:4218cf87-5dea-439d-9646-e9c8a49bb625

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hello Guys,   Can anyone please answer my question????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As your mentioned, I think some custom field types are not installed properly in your site collection. Please firstly check the type of fields in your list template. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I face this issue in all lists, How can I find this specific field to delete it?